# Schematic Question with electronic button

Tags: schematics, button

I have a question about this schematic, the arrows with the lines going thru them.

what I'm trying to do is hook up a push button, either a:

- 2-wire push button,
  or a
- 4-wire push button  (Push Buttons that look like on this PDF):

  - http://ardx.org/src/circ/CIRC07-sheet-OOML.pdf

whichever type of button is required. (I don't want to blow the circuit).

Here is the Diagram:

---

[image]

---

What I'm trying to do is this.. We own a coin operated washing machine in a building & we want to give family free washing, but the other tenents will pay. we want to hide the button being its very small in a discrete location somewhere.. I'm not worried about the hiding part.

I need to know looking at the Diagram, how would I go about that? would I use a 2 wire push button or a 4 wire like in the above PDF (i have those on hand). from videos I have seen & research I have read.. I am guessing wires # 1 & 4 (Blue & White/Blue) ?

But I dont understand what the wires # 2 & 3 do? they have the same arrows with lines going thru them.

And do I need more then just a push button? like a resistor or something too?

I'm sorry, I am not very good at this, any help would be appreciated.

** EDIT:
I am adding in the full Schematic so you can see.. if you tell me to run a wire from point 'A' to point'B'.. I will do whatever it takes to make this work, again please any help would be appreciated.. I don't know what to do.

[image]

Comment: Why not just give them 10 coins per month - they get 10 washes per month and any more have to be paid for. You do realise that to use the button they have to be alone in the room otherwise the secret gets out... which it will anyway.

Comment: @SolarMike, its a small room & the family won't say anything (family being 3 people)

Comment: In the schematic there are two optics like the one in the picture. You use two kind of coins? Can you also post a picture of the coin comparator you use? It might not work with only a switch.

Comment: its just a US quarter slot, 6 quarters.. thats it, also ONLY - AA4 is used (coin sensor), theres only 4 wires coming out of coin area

Comment: I found the datasheet, so it's a dumb mechanical coin comparator or an external accept/reject device and the opto is used only to see if a coin has been validated. The only security measure is a timeout of 8 seconds for the opto blocked state. This is rather permissive, use The Photon solution but warn the family to push the button less than 8 seconds per coin.

Comment: @Dorian, I left The Photon a msg, but no reply yet.. if you understand how this works, can you write an answer below and explain step by step what i have to do, i dont get it, i'm a programmer, not an electrician.. i know the basics.. i need help..

Comment: Cut the wire that goes to pin 2 not to close to connector, not to close to the sensor board. Get a push button that has a normal closed contact, if you're not sure then goto an electronic store and ask the seller to also show you the two normal closed contact pins where you will connect the two wires. Here is one but I'm sure you can find one at a local store: https://www.ebay.com/itm/Push-Button-Momentary-Switch-Normally-Closed/151837949523?hash=item235a3f3e53:g:f3YAAOSwNgxWEQnK

Comment: The one that you have in the link cannot be found in the normal closed version due their small size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The device in the diagram is an opto-interruptor. When the coin drops, it breaks the light beam from the LED (the upper "arrow with a line through it") to the photo-transistor (the lower "arrow with a line through it").

Some other board in the system will be providing power to both pin 1 and pin 2. When current through the photo-transistor stops, it will likely be interpreted as a coin drop.

If you break the wire from connector pin 2 and the photo-transistor, and put a momentary normally-closed switch (be careful about just taking any switch from your junk drawer: normally-open switches are probably more common than normally-closed) in series you will likely be able to fake a coin drop. Breaking any of the wires and inserting an NC switch would actually be likely to work (either by cutting off power to the LED) or breaking the PT circuit like the PT would do in the event of a coin drop.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response, I edited it & added FULL schematic.. any ideas?

Comment: and it is only those (AA4) coin sensor wires, (4) of them that come thru from the coin box area to the board, no other wires, just those 4

Comment: i'm sorry.. @Dorian even said your way would work. But I dont understand what you mean.. can you tell me more detailed how to do what you said.. i get pin 2, break the wire, do something.. lol.. please help me